# Custom ActiveMQ Producer Port

Tags: java, jms, port, activemq-classic, producer

I've implemented a JMS producer and a consumer, which are deployed in two different host both in a DMZ.
[Here](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-define-a-local-address-and-local-port-for-tcp-or-ssl.html) I read how to define a custom host and port for the producer. But I don't understand where I have to put that line.

Here is my code:

```
Connection connection = null;
    try{

        System.out.println("Connecting to "+getBrokerUrl());
        connection = (new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(getBrokerUrl())).createConnection();
        connection.start();

        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Topic topic = session.createTopic(this.topicName);

        TextMessage txtMsg = session.createTextMessage();
                    txtMsg.setText(msg);
                    txtMsg.setJMSType(msgType);

        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(topic);
                        producer.send(txtMsg);

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        try{
            connection.close();
        }
        catch(JMSException je){
            System.out.println("Unable to close connection: "+je.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Doing
`tcp://myBrokerHost:61616/localhost:60606` I obtain the following error:
`java.net.ConnectException: Invalid Argument` I think that the problem is the resolution of _localhost_

Answer (score 0):

Should be in ActiveMQConnectionFactory instance which you are passing the getBrokerUrl() result:

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
```

Comment: If I replace getrokerUrl() with "vm://localhost" how can I specify the brokerUrl?

Comment: should be u url this an example only

Comment: So that line should become:
      `ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://myBrokerHost:61616/localhost:60606");`

and the producer should publish on myBrokerHost from the port 60606?

Comment: Create a separate ActiveMQConnectionFactory for each host and separate MessageProducer

Comment: Maybe I was not able to correctly explain the problem...
I have only one connection from a producer (localhost) to the broker (myBrokerHost).
The broker is listening on the default port 61616; how can I force my producer on localhost to send message from a specific port (e.g. 60606)?

Comment: Doing `tcp://myBrokerHost:61616/localhost:60606` I obtain the following error: `java.net.ConnectException: Invalid Argument` I think that the problem is the resolution of localhost